# How to kill some one app when you known Name app or identify of app ?

Tags: objective-c, c

I have problem is use CTCall action call to some number, when call failed I can not close call screen,
I know name of call Screen app and identify of it but not kill it , Help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot terminate another app on iOS.

Comment: Perhaps he's on the Mac...

Comment: CTCall is not on the Mac.

Comment: Oh, I see; OK then ;)

Comment: How to disable Callscreen to background or disconnect call when call with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",Num]]];

Comment: if you Replace "tel" with "telprompt" so you are accept the firts ,how to Call and auto close Call Screen when finished ???